# ResultSet could be possibly null, how to fix this?

Tags: java, mysql, exception, intellij-idea, javafx

It tells me that the "userRow" ResultSet could be null, do you guys know how can I fix this or why is it happening, I would greatly appreciate it, thanks.

It tells me to add more details: I created this ResultSet method in order to retrieve information from the MySQL database that I made with MySQL Workbench, I'm trying to retrieve the information of the USER_TABLE, username, and password, so it would get the info from these two columns and then check with the database and allow the login. But it has been giving me the exception that the ResultSet might be null, I also indicated the specific location of the error right in the code.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Thanks.

here are my two classes involved with the issue:

```
public class Login {

@FXML
private TextField userNameTextField;

@FXML
private PasswordField passwordPasswordField;

@FXML
private Button signUpButton;

@FXML
private Button loginButton;

private sample.database.dbHandler dbHandler;

@FXML
void initialize() {

    dbHandler = new dbHandler();


    loginButton.setOnAction(event -> {

        String loginText = userNameTextField.getText().trim();
        String loginPassword = passwordPasswordField.getText().trim();

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(loginText);
        user.setPassword(loginPassword);

        ResultSet userRow = dbHandler.getUser(user);

        int counter = 0;

        try {

            while (userRow.next()) { //it says that "userRow" could possibly be null

                counter++;

            }

            if (counter == 1) {

                System.out.println("Logged in");

            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    });

    signUpButton.setOnAction(event -> {

        signUpButton.getScene().getWindow().hide();

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("/sample/signup.fxml"));

        try {

            loader.load();

        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        Parent root = loader.getRoot();
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.showAndWait();

    });

}
```

---

```
public class dbHandler extends Config {

java.sql.Connection Connection;

public Connection getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://" + dbHost + ":" + dbPort + "/" + dbName;

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");

    Connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString, dbUser, dbPass);

    return Connection;

}

public void signUp(User user) {

    String insert = "INSERT INTO " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + "(" + Constants.USERS_FIRSTNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_LASTNAME + "," +
            Constants.USERS_USERNAME + "," + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + ")" + "VALUES(?,?,?,?)";

    try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, user.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, user.getPassword());

        preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

public ResultSet getUser(User user) {

    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    if (!user.getUsername().equals("") || !user.getPassword().equals("")) {

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + " WHERE " + Constants.USERS_USERNAME + "=?"
                + " AND " + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + "=?";

    try {

        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());

        preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    } else {

        System.out.println("Error");

    }

    return resultSet;

}
```

Comment: th easiest way if to check for null: `if (userRow == null ) return;`

Comment: java naming conventions please

Answer (score 2):

If you format your code so as to make it easier to read, you will see that method `getUser()`, in class `dbHandler`, will return null if both *username* and *password* are empty. When that is the case, you simply print "Error" to the screen and continue. You may be sure that those two values will never be empty, but the compiler doesn't know that. If it is an error when both *username* and *password* are empty, then throw an `Exception`.

```
public ResultSet getUser(User user) {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    if (!user.getUsername().equals("") || !user.getPassword().equals("")) {
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + Constants.USERS_TABLE + " WHERE "
                + Constants.USERS_USERNAME + "=?" + " AND " + Constants.USERS_PASSWORD + "=?";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = getConnection().prepareStatement(query);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getUsername());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, user.getPassword());
            preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
    return resultSet;
}
```

What about replacing this line

```
System.out.println("Error");
```

with

```
throw new RuntimeException("Missing username and/or password.");
```